# elasticsearch watcher could not parse search input

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py, elasticsearch-watcher

I'm trying to configure an Elasticsearch Watcher Watch to alert on certain messages, but I'm unable to get my search input to work.
I tried using both Sense and [elasticsearch-watcher-py](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-watcher-py), but Watcher always returns a "parse_exception".

```
est.watcher.put_watch(
    id='a1b_error',
    body={
        # run the watch every night at midnight
        'trigger': { 'schedule': { 'daily': { 'at': 'midnight' }}},
        'condition': { 'script': { 'inline': 'ctx.payload.hits.total > 0' } },
        'input': {
            'search': {
                'requests': {
                    'indices': ['logstash-*'],
                    'body': {
                        'query': {
                            'bool': {
                                'must': [
                                    { 'match': { 'Projekt': 'ourproject' }},
                                    { 'match': { 'Modus': 'production' }},
                                    { 'match': { 'facility': 'somebackend.log' }},
                                    { 'wildcard': { 'message': 'SOMEERROR*' }},
                                    { 'range': { '@timestamp' : { 'gte': 'now-30d', 'lt': 'now' }}}
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        'actions': {
            'log' : {
                'logging' : {
                    'test': 'Watch triggered!'
                }
            }
        }
    }
)
```

Using elasticsearch-py and the exact same search query it returns 186 results just fine, but Watcher keeps returning a status 400 and a parse_exception with the reason "could not parse [search] input for watch [testwatch]. unexpected token [START_OBJECT]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As someone on the [elastic forum](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/problem-creating-watch-unable-to-parse-search-input/57799) pointed out to me, it was merely a typo.

```
'requests': {
```

should really be

```
'request': {
```

Also, for completeness sake, there's an error in my action, the following would be correct.

```
'actions': {
    'log' : {
        'logging' : {
            'text': 'Watch triggered!'
        }
    }
}
```